# Can someone confirm Mathematica crash on Mac with external screen?

Tags: crash, mac-os-x

I ran into a reproducible problem with my Mathematica, I was wondering if it's something that is true for other users, and not just in on my machine.

**Setup:** MacBook with one external monitor in clamshell mode. Run Mathematica 11, and open any two m-files. (it has to be m-files, it does not happen with nb-files, and it has to be two of them)

**Steps:** disconnect the external monitor by pulling the connecter, then open the laptop lid.

**Effect:** Mathematica has crashed.

---

Mathematica

- Version Number: 11.1.0.0
- Platform: Mac OS X x86 (32-bit, 64-bit Kernel)

Computer:

- MacBook Pro
- Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6

### Edit

Some more details about the crashes: I realized that the crashes also happen with .nb-files. I am pretty sure that the problem has to do with the way Mathematica windows interact with the screen resolution and their placement on the screen. The Mathematica usually freezes when I have open .nb-files that extend over big portions of the external screen. When I disconnect the external screen and go from clamshell mode to the normal mode the resolution changes, which causes Mathematica to freeze.

It seems there is a way to avoid the freezing. Before disconnecting the external screen resize all Mathematica windows to small squares and place them roughly in the upper left corner of the screen. The problem does not occur any more. It is as if now the windows are small enough so that the screen resolution change does not affect them any more.

Comment: Works fine for me 11.1.1.0 OSX 10.11.6. I do see lots of crashes coming out of sleep, or restoring windows after a restart, but I've never tried to isolate the behavior.

Comment: I have a similar problem, starting in the last few weeks, presumably with a recent update (no facts on that). However, nb-files seem leave mine hung. I don't have data on (or use) m-file. Same Mac and Mac OS, same Mathematica version and platform.

Comment: I reported something similar to technical support a few months ago, they confirmed it was a known issue. Can't find case number. I'd contact them if I were you.

Comment: I'm having similar problems with Mathematica 11.2 on macOS, again involving external monitors, and nb files. I haven't been able to find a way to reproduce it.